# Unable to send JSON object to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am unable to send JSON object to XMLHttpRequest(). However, if I send string data through send(), it works. For example, the following code works:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://xyz.info/api/contacts';
xhr.open("POST", url,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
     if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
                // Request finished. Do processing here.
     }
}
xhr.send("apikey=ee694eabf9e3&firstname=Raja1&lastname=Kumars&phone=123456");
```

However, if I try to send data using JSON, it posts nothing to the url. The following code does not work.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://xyz.info/api/contacts';
    xhr.open("POST", url,true);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
            // Request finished. Do processing here.
        }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
                    'apikey' :'ee6915d4ee4b4df66bba82277e3',
                    'firstname' : 'Kumar',
                    'lastname' : 'Sunder',
                    'phone':'5557773334'
    }));
```

Comment: In the second example you are sending a string. Not exactly a json Object.

Comment: @Matthias a string representation of a javascript object, though.  I still don't know what a json object is (doesn't exist).

Comment: Dumb question, but does the API support posts of type `application/json`?  Have you checked browser devtools network tab to see what your code is actually posting?

Comment: James, sorry for the dumb question, I am new to JavaScript. I tried both 'application/json' as well as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Both did not work. My intention was to have a properly formatted send() through JSON.stringify(). In the second example, it does not post anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending very different information in your two calls. Some sample code:

`var _stringify = JSON.stringify({
                    'apikey' :'ee6915d4ee4b4df66bba82277e3',
                    'firstname' : 'Kumar',
                    'lastname' : 'Sunder',
                    'phone':'5557773334'
    });
    console.log(_stringify);
    var _orig = "apikey=ee694eabf9e3&firstname=Raja1&lastname=Kumars&phone=123456"
    var _encoded = encodeURI(_stringify);
    console.log(_orig);
    console.log(_encoded);`

when your original string is printed to the console log, it looks as you would expect:

`apikey=ee694eabf9e3&firstname=Raja1&lastname=Kumars&phone=123456`

when the result of JSON.stringify is printed to the console, it returns: 

`{"apikey":"ee6915d4ee4b4df66bba82277e3","firstname":"Kumar","lastname":"Sunder","phone":"5557773334"}`

That is, it comes complete with lots of extra double quote marks and left and right brackets. If you want to send all of that as a string (as in your initial example), you would need to URI encode the result of the JSON.stringify call. This is what happens with the "_encoded" variable, which contains: 

`%7B%22apikey%22:%22ee6915d4ee4b4df66bba82277e3%22,%22firstname%22:%22Kumar%22,%22lastname%22:%22Sunder%22,%22phone%22:%225557773334%22%7D`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending via a POST action, but then sending the data via a url string.  If you want to send it that way you need to set it to GET.

Comment: I'm not seeing that.  The first case is a POST via traditional html form-type, the second is POST via application/json type.  It's true that the data serialization of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` looks similar to a querystring.